# Pass parameters via JSON to a modal popup in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, popup, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal popup in an ASP.NET MVC3 application, and pass it some parameters.
The popup contains a view defined in a file called `SearchArea.cshtml`

So, here is what I wrote :

**My view :**

```
var coordinates = [];

//push some data in coordinates
//coordinates looks like : coordinates[0] = 45.25489, coordinates[1] = 5.14975, etc...

$("<div></div>")
    .addClass("dialog")
    .appendTo("body")
    .dialog({
        title: "TEST",  
        close: function () { $(this).remove(); },  
        modal: true,  
        height: 400,  
        width: 600,  
        left: 0
   }).load('@Url.Action("Show", "SearchArea")', {'coordinates' : JSON.stringify(coordinates) });
```

**My controller**

```
public ActionResult Show(string coordinates)
{
    List<Single> searchArea = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Single>>(coordinates);
    return View(searchArea);
}
```

However, this is what I obtain :

[image: popupModal]

When I debug step-by-step, `searchArea` has good values, so I think serialization / deserialization are OK. The view that should be loaded is OK too, I tried to display it and no error occurs.

Where am I wrong ? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336834/mvc-passing-parameters-from-view-to-popup/11343262) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745085/how-to-display-asp-net-mvc-3-view-as-a-popup) and a lot of others, but I can't correct my mistakes... Can someone help me ?

Comment: Show us the "Show" view,

Comment: As I said, I tried to display the show view via another method and it perfectly works, so I don't think the problem is there. Moreover, the code is huge and not really interesting

Comment: When you debug in the view, is your model ok?

Comment: Did you try returning a PartialView instead of a View ?

Comment: I didn't try in this case because this is a "real view", with textboxes, radiobuttons etc... I did the same with a partial view some times ago and it worked, but in my case, it doesn't really make sens to create a partial view here. It's a personnal project, I don't have deadline, and I'd love to create something complient with standards and common sense. But tell me if I'm wrong and if partial view could be used in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution yesterday.

Instead of stringified an array, I stringified `coordinates.Join(',')`. This works, but this is ugly.
So I'm working on created an model containing all wanted fields, then pass it to my view. It should work, I tried with dummies values and it seems to work